# Compiled MATLAB error: Undefined function 'ft_datatype_sens' for input arguments of type 'struct'

Tags: matlab, mcc, matlab-spm

I have a MATLAB program written by one of my users which makes use of the SPM8 toolbox.  If run directly, it works fine.  However, when compiled and then run, the following error occurs:

```
Undefined function 'ft_datatype_sens' for input arguments of type 'struct'
```

This function comes from the Fieldtrip toolbox, which is bundled with the SPM8 toolbox.  The `startup.m` contains the following:

```
if(isdeployed==false)
    addpath(genpath('/cm/shared/apps/matlab/spm/08'))
    spm('defaults', 'eeg')
    spm_get_defaults('cmdline',true)
    disp('SPM path is set')
end
```

Not being a MATLAB user myself, I am groping in the dark, but my assumption is that the Fieldtrip toolbox is not being found.

Can anyone shed any light on this?

Comment: Compiled applications do not support changing path. If you are compiling the program, try using the "-C' flag of mcc to inspect the generated package file using a zip utility for the files present.

Comment: Thanks for the hint.  The package does indeed contain the file 'ft_datatype_sens.m', so that seems OK.  However, I don't understand what you mean by "changing the path".  Isn't the path just whatever I set before compiling and is just compiled into the standalone binary?  Or should I move the external toolbox into the 'toolbox' directory of the MATLAB installation?

Comment: If the file is there and path is added before compiling it should work. Not sure what else is causing the error. I would start with a simple call into the toolbox to check whether it is for this function or the entire toolbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is that the necessary directories need to be explicitly given via the option `-I`:

```
mcc -C -mv -R -singleCompThread -R -nodisplay -I /cm/shared/apps/matlab/spm/08/ -I /cm/shared/apps/matlab/spm/08/spm_orthviews -I /cm/shared/apps/matlab/spm/08/config -I /cm/shared/apps/matlab/spm/08/matlabbatch -I /cm/shared/apps/matlab/spm/08/matlabbatch/cfg_confgui -I /cm/shared/apps/matlab/spm/08/matlabbatch/cfg_basicio -I /cm/shared/apps/matlab/spm/08/matlabbatch/cfg_basicio/src -I /cm/shared/apps/matlab/spm/08/matlabbatch/examples -I /cm/shared/apps/matlab/spm/08/src -I /cm/shared/apps/matlab/spm/08/toolbox -I /cm/shared/apps/matlab/spm/08/toolbox/mixture -I /cm/shared/apps/matlab/spm/08/toolbox/spectral -I /cm/shared/apps/matlab/spm/08/toolbox/Seg -I /cm/shared/apps/matlab/spm/08/toolbox/Beamforming -I /cm/shared/apps/matlab/spm/08/toolbox/DEM -I /cm/shared/apps/matlab/spm/08/toolbox/DARTEL -I /cm/shared/apps/matlab/spm/08/toolbox/MEEGtools -I /cm/shared/apps/matlab/spm/08/toolbox/Neural_Models -I /cm/shared/apps/matlab/spm/08/toolbox/dcm_meeg -I /cm/shared/apps/matlab/spm/08/toolbox/SRender -I /cm/shared/apps/matlab/spm/08/toolbox/Shoot -I /cm/shared/apps/matlab/spm/08/toolbox/HDW -I /cm/shared/apps/matlab/spm/08/toolbox/FieldMap -I /cm/shared/apps/matlab/spm/08/EEGtemplates -I /cm/shared/apps/matlab/spm/08/canonical -I /cm/shared/apps/matlab/spm/08/rend -I /cm/shared/apps/matlab/spm/08/apriori -I /cm/shared/apps/matlab/spm/08/templates -I /cm/shared/apps/matlab/spm/08/external -I /cm/shared/apps/matlab/spm/08/external/fieldtrip -I /cm/shared/apps/matlab/spm/08/external/fieldtrip/plotting -I /cm/shared/apps/matlab/spm/08/external/fieldtrip/fileio -I /cm/shared/apps/matlab/spm/08/external/fieldtrip/statfun -I /cm/shared/apps/matlab/spm/08/external/fieldtrip/src -I /cm/shared/apps/matlab/spm/08/external/fieldtrip/connectivity -I /cm/shared/apps/matlab/spm/08/external/fieldtrip/inverse -I /cm/shared/apps/matlab/spm/08/external/fieldtrip/specest -I /cm/shared/apps/matlab/spm/08/external/fieldtrip/forward -I /cm/shared/apps/matlab/spm/08/external/fieldtrip/utilities -I /cm/shared/apps/matlab/spm/08/external/fieldtrip/preproc -I /cm/shared/apps/matlab/spm/08/external/fieldtrip/trialfun -I /cm/shared/apps/matlab/spm/08/external/yokogawa -I /cm/shared/apps/matlab/spm/08/external/eeprobe -I /cm/shared/apps/matlab/spm/08/external/mne -I /cm/shared/apps/matlab/spm/08/external/ctf -I /cm/shared/apps/matlab/spm/08/external/bemcp -I /cm/shared/apps/matlab/spm/08/tpm myprog.m
```

It is probably possible to reduce the number of directories which need to be specified by using the option `-a`, which can add directories recursively.